# YII2 не сохраняется модель

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, запрос, модель-данных

Не удается сохранить модель, выдает приведенную ниже ошибку. В нагугленных подобных вопросах везде все решалось правилами валидации, они у меня есть и это не помогает, в чем проблема?

Модель :

```
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{    
    public $name;
    public $price;

    public static function tableName(): string
    {
        return 'products';
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            ['name','string'],
            ['price','integer'],
            [['name','price'],'required']

        ];
    }
}
```

Код в контроллере:

```
$model = new Product();
$model->name = 'z';
$model->price = 5;
$model->insert();
```

Ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица в бд:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вот так `$model = new Product(['name' => 'z', 'price' => 5.0]); $model->insert();` ?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум надо пробовать так:

```
$model = new Product(['name' => 'z', 'price' => 5.0]); 
$model->insert();
```

Или использовать метод `load` для загрузки данных в модель.

В целом сейчас, если я понимаю, данные просто заносятся в поля модели, а не необходимые атрибуты модели (да это немного разные вещи). В итоге значения в модели пустые. (Валидация **не отрабатывает** именно из-за этого) А в БД не установлено значение по умолчанию в колонку `name` на случай, если будет передано пустое значение. В итоге и ошбика соответствующая..

Если может быть такая ситуация, что передаётся пустое значение, но нужно чтобы БД не ругалась - тогда надо в БД значение это задать

###### Также нужно удалить публичные свойства, т.к. на текущий момент это *виртуальные поля* модели и для работы с БД они не используются. Обычно виртуальные поля используются где-то внутри модели в какой-то логике.

---

Валидация не отрабатывает по двум причинам:

1. Описана в самом начале, т.к. данные по факту и не загружены в модель
2. **Никакого метода validate() у модели не вызвано**. Соответственно как может что-то отвалидироваться, если метод валидации не был вызван? Ответ - никак.

Comment: load пробовал, результат аналогичный

Comment: $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($model->validate()) {
                $model->save();
            } и метод validate() тоже вызывал, вместе с load

Comment: Дописал в ответ:  Также нужно удалить публичные свойства, т.к. на текущий момент это *виртуальные поля* модели и для работы с БД они не используются. Обычно виртуальные поля используются где-то внутри модели в какой-то логике.